Semaphore between submissions vs global barrier
When you submit one or multiple command buffers you can specify a semaphore that is signalled and awaited. This obviously can be used to prevent any subsequent submissions from beginning before the previous ones have completed. But I was thinking, since barriers apply to everything in the queue, even on things in different submissions, the semaphore method should be equivalent to placing a global barrier with something like VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT, and ensuring all memory (writes/reads) are made available/visible, right? They should be the same thing. If it is, what's the difference, I mean like, on a technical level? Is one more efficient than the other.

I would expect semaphores to be more expensive than pipeline barriers because their implementation requires more CPU-GPU interaction (CPU can wait on a sem), whereas pipeline barriers can be entirely handled by the GPU alone (CPU cannot wait on a pipeline barrier).
In terms of use case, note that there is no such thing as a global pipeline barrier. Pipeline barriers are scoped to the command stream in the queue they are submitted to. If you want to do cross-queue synchronization, then you cannot use pipeline barriers to implement that and need to use a semaphore to do that.
